# Binding to individual elements in a collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, mvvm, collections

I am fairly new to MVVM, so bear with.  I have a view model class that has a public property implemented as so:

```
public List<float> Length
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

In my XAML for the view, I have several text boxes, with each one bound to a specific element in this Length list:

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Length[0], Converter=DimensionConverter}" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Length[2], Converter=DimensionConverter}" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Length[4], Converter=DimensionConverter}" />
```

The DimensionConverter is a IValueConverter derived class that formats the values like a dimension (i.e. 480.0 inches becomes 40'0" in the text box on screen), and back again (i.e. takes 35'0" for a string and yield 420.0 inches for the source)

My issue: I need to be able to validate each value in the List as it is changed in the associated TextBox.  For some, I may need to modify other values in the List depending on the entered value (i.e. change the float at Length[0] will change the value at Length[4] and update the screen).

Is there any way to re-work the property to allow for an indexer?  Or, do I need to create individual properties for each item in the List (which really makes the List unnecessary)?  Essentially, since I already have the collection of float, I was hoping to be able to write MVVM code to validate each item as it is modified.

Thoughts?  (and, thanks in advance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ObservableCollection<float>` instead of a `List<float>`, and handle the `CollectionChanged` event to detect when the user changes a value.

Comment: As far as I understand he not able to bind to the specific list item by an item index, have I missed something?

Comment: That's not what I understood. Apparently the OP wants to validate the user input, so he needs to detect when the user changes a value

Comment: Yep looks like I totally misunderstood the question

Comment: I have tested and I am able to bind to individual items in the collection property.  The values show in the view, and when I change the values, this is reflected in the collection.  However, the problem I have is that there are validation rules that need to be applied on each item when it is entered, not at the end when they've already been modified.

Comment: @user1088638, in this case you need to use a ValidationRule (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't something like this:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Length}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Converter=DimensionConverter}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Be close to what you want?
It will display the entire list, and allow the user to modify the values, which will be returned straight back to the list, as long as your IValueConverter implements ConvertBack.

Then do as Thomas said to validate, or implement an [ObservableLinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996425/observable-linkedlist)

What you do at the moment looks dirty already and it's barely a few lines of code..

Comment: The issue I have is the nature of the view I'm trying to create.  Essentially the view is for a building layout, so the Length items are the lengths of the walls, various configurations (rectangles, L-shapes, T-shapes, etc.).  The layout is shown as a diagram, with TextBox controls placed to enter the individual measurements.  I already have a List of walls, so I was hoping to simply access that in the bindings, rather than creating a boilerplate method for each item in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you can have a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged to have the properties provided the length of list is constant.

Comment: FYI : the ViewModel class that provides the Length property does implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1):

if you want validate your text input with mvvm then create a model that you can youse at your viewmodel

```
public class FloatClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ICollection parentList;

  public FloatClass(float initValue, ICollection pList) {
    parentList = pList;
    this.Value = initValue;
  }

  private float value;

  public float Value {
    get { return this.value; }
    set {
      if (!Equals(value, this.Value)) {
        this.value = value;
        this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged("Value");
      }
    }
  }

  private void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string propName) {
    var eh = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (eh != null) {
      eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

at your viewmodel you can use the model like this

```
public class FloatClassViewmModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public FloatClassViewmModel() {
    this.FloatClassCollection = new ObservableCollection<FloatClass>();
    foreach (var floatValue in new[]{0f,1f,2f,3f}) {
      this.FloatClassCollection.Add(new FloatClass(floatValue, this.FloatClassCollection));
    }
  }

  private ObservableCollection<FloatClass> floatClassCollection;

  public ObservableCollection<FloatClass> FloatClassCollection {
    get { return this.floatClassCollection; }
    set {
      if (!Equals(value, this.FloatClassCollection)) {
        this.floatClassCollection = value;
        this.RaiseOnPropertyChanged("FloatClassCollection");
      }
    }
  }

  private void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string propName) {
    var eh = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (eh != null) {
      eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

here is the xaml example

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FloatClassViewmModel.FloatClassCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter=DimensionConverter}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

hope this helps

Comment: I have thought about this approach.  I hesitate because it seems "plumbing heavy" to me, but I'm fairly new to MVVM, so that inkling is probably a leftover from my C++ days.