# Bindable collection which inserts at top and removes from bottom

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using an `ObservableCollection` to which 25 items will be added per second in a background thread. The items are added using `Insert` to 0th position. After a time period, old items are being removed in a background thread. The items at the end are being removed using `RemoveAt`. This collection is binded to a datagrid. CPU usage is increasing and the UI is not responsive since these operations are being done.

I have tried creating a custom stack and it won't satisfy the complete requirement as the items cannot be removed from bottom in an efficient way.

I need to create a bindable custom collection which inserts item to the top and removes from bottom in a very efficient manner.

Looking forward to any kind of input/suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Yes please, you can go ahead and create a custom collection. What is stopping you, please post that here.

Comment: Also try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996425/observable-linkedlist), it sounds like observable linked list is something you're looking for.

Comment: I am trying `ObservableLinkedList`. Though collection changed in implemented, UI is not getting updated. I had to refresh the collectionview which again increases the CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

How about deriving your custom collection from `ObservableCollection` and just adding the bare minimum of needed extra functionality? Something along the lines of

```
class ExtendedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void AddRange(int startingIndex, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var notifier = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, items.ToList(), startingIndex);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            // insert to the underlying collection to avoid change events
            Items.Insert(startingIndex++, item);
        }

        OnCollectionChanged(notifier);
    }

    public void RemoveRange(int startingIndex, int count)
    {
        // Do it yourself
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. Hope `Items` refers to the current object of the collection. I have done it the same way and inserting with index is expensive in my scenario.

Comment: @SubramaniamB I can't do much testing right now. My impression was that the visual construction of items with WPF would be more of a bottleneck compared to the background list handling and I was hoping to reduce this a bit by having a bulk-update instead of 25 single insert events. If my guess is right, you won't gain much by optimizing your work in the background.